# Apex Charts Range Bar Colors

Tags: javascript, charts, oracle-apex, apexcharts

Can you use a color array for range charts? I grabbed the same array that worked in a bar chart, but the colors are ignored in a range bar chart.

Comment: This is really going to depend on what version you're on. Are you using Anychart of OracleJET?

Comment: I think the latest version. The .js file says  ApexCharts v3.10.1.

Comment: https://codepen.io/JoeyEff/pen/jOEyPRN?editors=1010

Comment: This is a bug in ApexCharts which doesn't allow us to use different colors for each row in range-bar charts.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the examples out there show you how to set the color of a series. With the range chart, you end up with 1 series and multiple groups by default. However, you can set the color of individual items within a series too.

Go to the App Galery and install the Sample Charts app. Go to page 23 (the Range Chart) page, drill into the Attributes of the Range region, and scroll down until you see JavaScript Initialization Code. Add this function there:

```
function( options ){
  options.dataFilter = function( data ) {
    data.series[0].items[0].color = "#0B6623";
    data.series[0].items[1].color = "#9DC183";
    data.series[0].items[2].color = "#708238";
    data.series[0].items[3].color = "#C7EA46";
    data.series[0].items[4].color = "#3F704D";

    return data;
  };

  return options;
}
```

When you run the page you'll see that each item has a different color:

[image]